# How to generate request body regex match with spring restdocs and spring contract?

Tags: junit5, mockmvc, spring-cloud-contract, spring-restdocs

Using mockMvc, Spring restDocs and Spring cloud contract with the following `@Test` code:

```
var adminDTO = HandlerTestObjectGenerator.createRandomAdminDTO();

        mockMvc.perform(
                RestDocumentationRequestBuilders
                        .post("/api/admins")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(adminDTO))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        ).andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andDo(document("create-admin",
                        preprocessRequest(),
                        preprocessResponse(),
                        requestFields(
                                usernameFieldDescriptor,
                                passwordFieldDescriptor,
                                rolesFieldDescriptor
                        ),
                        responseFields(
                                admin_adminIdFieldDescriptor,
                                admin_usernameFieldDescriptor,
                                admin_rolesFieldDescriptor
                        ),
                        SpringCloudContractRestDocs.dslContract()
                ));
```

I get the following groovy contract:

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'POST'
        url '/api/admins'
        body('''{
  "username" : "6ddfee05-75c2-4cdb-b35e-668e79226e92",
  "password" : "91a96b76-283f-44eb-b6cc-72945872b287",
  "roles" : [ "ADMIN" ]
}''')
...
```

The request body values for `username` and `password` are  hardcoded in the groovy contract, making them unpredictable on the consumer side.

Instead of having them hardcoded, I would like to have regex pattern validation, so any valid input returns the contract`s response.

Can it be done?
Please provide concrete code as I am stuck with the documentation.

Comment: Have you read this section? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-rest-docs

Comment: I have, but there is no described how to set bodyMatchers/stubMatchers for request part of the contract.

Comment: In here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-rest-docs-contracts , value "foo" is posted in the request body, then it is tested with wiremocks verify method, but ends up in response`s bodyMatchers.